# Add a trustable people only option

Tags: feature-request

So I have some code, but it's private and I don't want it to be leaked, so I thought why don't we add an option when you're creating a post, that makes it so then only people above a certain reputation or maybe people with a certain badge can read it.

Comment: I'm curious. What exactly makes you think that users above certain reputation wouldn't "leak" your code? I'm as likely to "leak" anything I find here as when I had 50 reputation points. In 20 or 30 years, when I'm reaching 20k, I assume I'll be equally likely to repost stuff I find on the web...

Comment: *psst, there are already hidden Q/As ... you just don't know about them cause they are, well, hidden and only available to 30k+ :)*

Comment: I'd of course take your ideas and make a business from it. I've got high rep here because I am a ***smart person***.

Comment: If your code is really "confidential", SO seems like a bad place to post it considering the license that is attributed to it afterwards. Seems like a better solution would be to hire a higher level developer who could sign a confidentiality clause.

Comment: I don't know why, but I read this question as: "I can't be bothered with providing a minimal example of my issue and just want to post the whole code for you to debug it, but please don't leak". I guess I'm just paranoid, sorry :(.

Answer (score 39):

*High reputation* means that you participate a lot here or write good answers. It doesn't mean that one can trust those and share secrets with them.

Also, answers are *for everyone*. Not just for you, or a "Stack Overflow elite".

If your code is that "confidential", you shouldn't share it with random strangers on the Internet. Even if they do have some gold badges.